# Powerpoint VBA foreach skipping some valid shapes

Tags: vba, powerpoint, transparency, textrange

I do presentations with background wipes that are flowchart process shapes with the text "wipey" for yellow wipes and "wipeb" for blue wipes. When working out the animations for training slides, I place the wipes in front with 0.75 transparency. Once the wipe-animation order is correct and the wipes properly placed, I move the wipes behind the text with 0 transparency.
My Wipe_Back macro works fine but my Wipe_Front macro is only getting some of the wipes each time it is called. I have to call it multiple times to get all of the shapes moved forward. the macros are almost identical so I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I am a VBA newbie-ish!
both macros are shown below and I am also open to recommendations on more elegant practices in the code.

Wipe_Back (seems to work):

```
Sub Wipe_Back()
  Dim sld As slide
  Dim shp As Shape
  Dim str As String
  For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoAutoShape Then
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
              If shp.TextFrame.TextRange = "wipey" Then
                shp.Fill.Transparency = 0
                shp.ZOrder msoSendToBack
                'shp.Fill.Transparency = 0.75
                'shp.ZOrder msoBringToFront
              End If
              If shp.TextFrame.TextRange = "wipeb" Then
                shp.Fill.Transparency = 0
                shp.ZOrder msoSendToBack
                'shp.Fill.Transparency = 0.75
                'shp.ZOrder msoBringToFront
              End If
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
  Next sld
End Sub
```

Wipe_Front does not consistently work:

```
Sub Wipe_Front()
  Dim sld As slide
  Dim shp As Shape
  Dim str As String
  For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoAutoShape Then
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
              If shp.TextFrame.TextRange = "wipey" Then
                'shp.Fill.Transparency = 0
                'shp.ZOrder msoSendToBack
                shp.Fill.Transparency = 0.75
                shp.ZOrder msoBringToFront
              End If
              If shp.TextFrame.TextRange = "wipeb" Then
                'shp.Fill.Transparency = 0
                'shp.ZOrder msoSendToBack
                shp.Fill.Transparency = 0.75
                shp.ZOrder msoBringToFront
              End If
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
  Next sld
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the order of shapes (as changing the z-order does) or delete them in the midst of a For Each/Next loop, the results won't be what you expect.

If deleting shapes, you can use something like this:

For x = sld.Shapes.Count to 1 Step -1
  ' delete sld.Shapes(x) if it meets your conditions
Next

If changing the z-order, you may need to collect references to the shapes in an array and step through the array a shape at a time.

Comment: Hi, Steve - your response is getting me closer but I am still making newbie mistakes. Below is my attempt to store the handles into a dynamic array and then extract them to set the Transparency and ZOrder.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it! Steve Rindsberg pointed me in the right direction and I corrected the "On Error Resume Next" and now the routines are doing what was expected. Thanks for the help!

Wipe Front():

```
Sub Wipe_Front()
  Dim sld As slide
  Dim shp As Shape
  Dim str As String
  Dim wshps() As Shape, i As Long
  ReDim wshps(0 To 1)
  i = 0

  For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoAutoShape Then
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
              If shp.TextFrame.TextRange = "wipey" Then
                Set wshps(i) = shp
                i = i + 1
                ReDim Preserve wshps(0 To i) As Shape
              End If
              If shp.TextFrame.TextRange = "wipeb" Then
                Set wshps(i) = shp
                i = i + 1
                ReDim Preserve wshps(0 To i) As Shape
              End If
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
    For Each wshp In wshps
      On Error Resume Next
      wshp.Fill.Transparency = 0.75
      wshp.ZOrder msoBringToFront
      'wshp.Fill.Transparency = 0
      'wshp.ZOrder msoSendToBack
    Next wshp
  Next sld
End Sub
```

Wipe_Back():

```
Sub Wipe_Back_New()
  Dim sld As slide
  Dim shp As Shape
  Dim str As String
  Dim wshps() As Shape, i As Long
  ReDim wshps(0 To 1)
  i = 0

  For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoAutoShape Then
            If shp.HasTextFrame Then
              If shp.TextFrame.TextRange = "wipey" Then
                Set wshps(i) = shp
                i = i + 1
                ReDim Preserve wshps(0 To i) As Shape
              End If
              If shp.TextFrame.TextRange = "wipeb" Then
                Set wshps(i) = shp
                i = i + 1
                ReDim Preserve wshps(0 To i) As Shape
              End If
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
    For Each wshp In wshps
      On Error Resume Next
      'wshp.Fill.Transparency = 0.75
      'wshp.ZOrder msoBringToFront
      wshp.Fill.Transparency = 0
      wshp.ZOrder msoSendToBack
    Next wshp
  Next sld
End Sub
```

Comment: Congratulations!